# Как задать граф в языке C++ (Призма Мебиуса)

Tags: c++, графы

Здравствуйте, как задать такой граф в языке C++?

> Далее всюду n — натуральное число.
>   Назовем граф с множествами вершин
>
> ```
> V = {0, 1, 2, . . ., 2n−1}
> ```
>
> и ребер
>
> ```
> E = {(i, i + 1) | i = 0, 2n − 1, i четное} ∪ {(i, i + 2) | i = 0, 2n − 1}
> ```
>
> (сложение по модулю 2n) призмой P(n).

Для представления использую матрицу смежности.

Comment: Насколько я знаю, в Си нет специальных языковых средств для задания графов.

Comment: Ну, раз вы сделали матрицу смежности, забейте её рёбрами по индексам, которые предписывает определение множества рёбер. Вам почти прямым текстом алгоритм написан.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ну, у вас есть какая-то матрица смежности, типа

```
vector<vector<int>> V(2*n, vector<int>(2*n,0));
```

Дальше - просто циклами:

*{(i, i+1) | i = 0, 2n − 1, i четное}*

```
for(int i = 0; i < 2*n; ++i)
{ 
    if (i%2) continue;  // нечетное

    V[i%(2*n)][(i+1)%(2*n)] = 1;
    // Если не ориентированный -
    V[(i+1)%(2*n)][i%(2*n)] = 1;
}
```

*{(i, i+2) | i = 0, 2n − 1}* - аналогично

```
for(int i = 0; i < 2*n; ++i)
{ 
    V[i%(2*n)][(i+2)%(2*n)] = 1;
    // Если не ориентированный -
    V[(i+2)%(2*n)][i%(2*n)] = 1;
}
```

*"По-моему, так" (с) Пух*